# Volley request with headers and body params

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I need to make an api request which.

Two headers :

1. Accept
2. Authorization

Five body params.

1. Number
2. Make
3. Model
4. Description
5. Plates

Through postman everything works great. 
But when i try through android app i can't get through. 
Note: Login through the same host works great so the setup its not the problem i think my main problem is in api call.

```
public void add(View view) {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/trucks";
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
                            // parse response
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                        String errorMsg = "";
                        if (response != null && response.data != null) {
                            String errorString = new String(response.data);
                        }
                    }
                }
        ) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + myToken);
                return headers;
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                TextInputEditText number = findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextNumber);
                TextInputEditText make = findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextMake);
                TextInputEditText model = findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextModel);
                TextInputEditText description = findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextDescription);
                TextInputEditText plates = findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextPlates);

                params.put("number", number.getText().toString());
                params.put("make", make.getText().toString());
                params.put("model", model.getText().toString());
                params.put("description", description.getText().toString());
                params.put("plates", plates.getText().toString());
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(request);
    }
```

Edit: by Solution #1.

```
public void add(View view) throws JSONException {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    TextInputEditText number = findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextNumber);
    TextInputEditText make = findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextMake);
    TextInputEditText model = findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextModel);
    TextInputEditText description = findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextDescription);
    TextInputEditText plates = findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextPlates);

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("Number", number.getText().toString());
    jsonObject.put("Make", make.getText().toString());
    jsonObject.put("Model", model.getText().toString());
    jsonObject.put("Description", description.getText().toString());
    jsonObject.put("Plates", plates.getText().toString());
    final String requestBody = jsonObject.toString();

    JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/trucks", jsonObject,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            //now handle the response
            Toast.makeText(truck_add.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            //handle the error
            Toast.makeText(truck_add.this, "An error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }) {    //this is the part, that adds the header to the request
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Accept", "application/json");
            params.put("Authorization", myToken);
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(jsonRequest);
}
```

Postman : [image: Postman example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to pass the data through the body, you need to create a json object before string request.
try this way,
1. create a string url for request.
2. create json object for body data and pass data to it. Like,

```
JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject();  
jsonObject.put("Number", address.getNumber());  
jsonObject.put("Make", address.getMake());  
jsonObject.put("Model", address.getModel());  
jsonObject.put("Description", address.getDescription());  
jsonObject.put("Plates", address.getPlates());  
final String requestBody=jsonObject.toString();
```

3. After this, apply stringRequest.
4. Now, add below lines before header method and after error method.

```
@Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            try {
                return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                return null;
            }
```

5. In your getHeaders() method, use Content-Type for "application/json" and for Authorization you must use only token without (Bearer).
Done.

Comment: Can you please check Edit in my question. Did you thought on something like that . P.S still cant make it works

Answer (score 0):

```
public void add(View view) throws JSONException {
   String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/trucks";

   //removed views initialization from here.  
//you need to initialize views in oncreate() / oncreateView() method.  
/*first create json object in here.
then set keys as per required body format with values
*/
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("Number", number.getText().toString());
    jsonObject.put("Make", make.getText().toString());
    jsonObject.put("Model", model.getText().toString());
    jsonObject.put("Description", description.getText().toString());
    jsonObject.put("Plates", plates.getText().toString());
    final String requestBody = jsonObject.toString();

 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        // parse response
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                    String errorMsg = "";
                    if (response != null && response.data != null) {
                        String errorString = new String(response.data);
                    }
                }
            }
    )  {    //this is the part, that adds the header to the request
//this is where you need to add the body related methods
@Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        try {
            return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s 
using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
            return null;
        } 
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            params.put("Authorization", myToken);
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(jsonRequest);
}
```

**Put Log in every method to check which method being executed and for possible error**
If there is an error after this, then post error from logcat and we will solve it quickly.

Comment: im getting response `com.android.volley.ServerError` . I added postman example as well.

Comment: Is volley only way of sending requests ? . I wonder if there is another helper class since I'm newbie in android

Comment: In postman, You added data in body as format of form-urlencoded. Try it in raw by selecting format from dropdown as json and remove data from form.