# How to send POST of JSON raw body using volley?

Tags: java, android, json

While posting the raw data I also have to send the  parameters. Whatever I tried, I have not been able to post it with android java.

**my sample input is :**

[image]

My code is  - ApiService.class

```
 public void sendTest(String token,final TestConfig config) {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://.test.ir/public/api/v3/PropertyAssignment",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        config.onReceived(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if (error instanceof NoConnectionError || error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, NoInternet.class));

                        }

                        config.onError(error.getMessage());
                    }
                }) {

            @Nullable
            @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
//                params.put(Vars.KEY_AUTH, Vars.AUTH);
                hashMap.put("title", "hi");
                hashMap.put("address", "address1");
                hashMap.put("price", "200000");
                hashMap.put("region", "[6,8]");
                return hashMap;
            }
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
//                params.put(Vars.KEY_AUTH, Vars.AUTH);
                params.put(Vars.KEY_AUTH, token);
                params.put(Vars.KEY_USERNAME, Vars.USERNAME);
                params.put(Vars.KEY_PASSWORD, Vars.PASSWORD);
                return params;
            }


        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }
```

call

```
ApiService  apiService = new ApiService(this);

apiService.sendTest(new UserSharedPref(this).getUserToken(),
        new ApiService.TestConfig() {
            @Override
            public void onReceived(String res) {
                Log.i("alllllllllllllll",res);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String errorCode) {

            }
        });
```

My sample input that i want to send to the web service and i can't send it  with params.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54497699/volley-request-with-headers-and-body-params

Comment: Please remove the *.* in your URL  https://test.ir/public/api/v3/PropertyAssignment

Answer (score 0):

Please check below URL

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://test.ir/public/api/v3/PropertyAssignment",
```